# Why did it always missing one subplot when I import mnist digits dataset?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, figure, mnist

I want to import mnist digits digits to show in one figure, and code like that,

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
n = 0
for i in range (5):
    for j in range (5):
        plt.subplot(5, 5, i*5 +j +1)
   
        plt.imshow(X_train[n], cmap='Greys')
        plt.title("Digit:{}".format(y_train[n]))
        n += 1
        plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, no matter I change the row and col, it always missing one subplot on the bottom,like that
[image] I don't know what did it happen here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this bug too.  It seems to be related to the `plt.tight_layout()` that you apply within the loop.  Instead of doing this, use [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to produce the axes objects first, then iterate over those instead.  Once you plot everything, use `tight_layout` on the opened figure:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=5, figsize=(8,8))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(X_train[i], cmap='Greys')
    ax.set_title("Digit:{}".format(y_train[i]))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

We now get what is expected:

[image]